# Alternative to Jupiter Applet

Tags: 13.04, laptop, power-management

Wondering if anyone knows of any alternative to the Jupiter applet that stopped being actively developed?  I found this, but it's all I could find:

http://itsfoss.com/solve-overheating-issue-battery-life-ubuntu-1304/

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use indicator-cpufreq. It is not an exact equivalent to jupiter but it's good, even better in controlling the cpu. Does not change screen brightness.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```