# CPU temperature indicator alternative to jupiter

Tags: gnome-panel, temperature

I was happily using jupiter and now it is not supported anymore. I am on 64bit ubuntu 12.04 using gnome-panel. I am just looking for an applet that will give my my cpu temperature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the CPU temperature?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature). Also see [Jupiter in Ubuntu 13.10 (Laptop Overheating)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360549/jupiter-in-ubuntu-13-10-laptop-overheating) and [Alternative to Jupiter Applet](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304270/alternative-to-jupiter-applet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Hardware Sensors Indicator. [Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors) It should work fine in gnome-panel.